# Search query sorting by phrase not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-mapping

This is my current setup the I have for my user_info index

```
PUT user_info
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "username": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "autocomplete": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "autocomplete"
          },
          "raw": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
          }
        }
      },
      "telephone": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "autocomplete": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "autocomplete"
          },
          "raw": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "edge_ngram_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      },
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [],
          "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "edge_ngram_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I run this search query

```
GET user_info/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "username.autocomplete": {
              "query": "Eli Hub"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "prefix": {
            "username.raw": {
                "value": "Eli Hub"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

These are the results

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "user_info",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.9736931,
        "_source": {
          "username": "Eli Huber"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "user_auth_cards_info",
        "_id": "6",
        "_score": 0.518771,
        "_source": {
          "username": "Elly Eli"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "user_info",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.50130737,
        "_source": {
          "username": "Sherlyn Eli"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "user_info",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.47586513,
        "_source": {
          "e_name": "Eli Rios"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "user_auth_cards_info",
        "_id": "7",
        "_score": 0.3256223,
        "_source": {
          "username": "Eli "
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "user_info",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.31583264,
        "_source": {
          "username": "Eli Bender"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "user_info",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 0.31583264,
        "_source": {
          "username": "Breanna Eli"
        }
      }
    ]
```

I don't understand how I would go about sorting these results and getting them to all start with Eli first or if it's even possible with the index setup I have. Initially I had a prefix query setup with a boost of 2 and then a wildcard query. Which worked however it would be a performance issue at a later stage so trying to figure it out this way.

1. EliHuber...
2. Eli....
3. ....Eli

Comment: About performance, what is the size of the index, of the documents, the average number of indexed documents?

Comment: @rabbitbr We have about 3 million documents, the documents are around 10kb.

Comment: See this [discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/match-phrase-score-by-order/116771/4), despite being old, I know that a lot hasn't changed since then. Maybe if you use the completion suggester you can control the order through the weights but I really agree with the sentence: "If you really want to take the token position into account I think you need to pay too much of a price for autocomplete and you' d also need to use payloads"